# problem with exporting 3d models as fbx

Tags: uv, export, uv-image-editor, .fbx

[image: inside blender]

[image: after exporting]

i tried exporting in fbx format, but facing problem. please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is your case but sometimes when there is not a proper flow of the loops in the modeling or when is not properly triangulated or quadrangulated that could happens.